# Update Document Template Dynamically in Alfresco from property page

Tags: alfresco-share

I have one document template as like attached screen shot. now my requirement is i want to dynamically update some values  of that document when i will upload it in alfresco site. i will either create that Document through node template or upload. I want to provide those values from document property page. 
can anyone help me how can i achieve this.

I tried it using java script, but i am getting some problem. so i am thinking for using Alfresco CMIS API. But i am quite new in alfresco cmis. so can any one tell the better way which i can use for this task.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should trigger an custom action by a [Rule](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html)

When someone update a node (for example by editing properties), your action will be triggered and you will be able to :

- get the content of your node
- get the properties of your node
- use the apache poi library provided by alfresco  (my guess is that you use word documents) to find your parameters, and the replace them by the value you find in the property nodes.

[Here](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html) is an excellent tutorial to learn how to create a custom action.

Note : You may have to keep the original templated document if you want to change a second time your properties (by using versionning for example).

**Edit (see discussion below) :**

I assume you know how to use rules in alfresco : http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/library-folder-rules-define.html

1. Declare a new action to assign to a rule. This action must be triggered **when the excel is dropped or updated**

   1. Create an action implementing your need :

      ```
      public class MyAction extends ActionExecuterAbstractBase {
      ...

          @Override
          protected void executeImpl(final Action arg0, final NodeRef arg1) {
              // your code here
          }
      ....
      }
      ```

      This action will :

      1. Take the nodeRef parameter (which is the excel file) and load the file

         ```
         ...
         Inputstream inputstream = getFileFolderService().getReader(arg1).getContentInputStream();
         ...
         NPOIFSFileSystem fs = null;
         HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
         try {
         fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(inputstream);
         workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);
         //get your data with POI
         ```
      2. For each row of your excel :

         1. Make a copy of your template :

            - find it :

              ```
              getSearchService().query(searchParameters)
              ```
            - copy it :

              ```
              getFileFolderService().copy(sourceNodeRef, targetParentRef, newName)
              ```
         2. Do transformations of your new word content (Find occurrences and replace with poi library).
         3. Update the content of your new file :

            ```
            ContentWriter writerDoc = getContentService().getWriter(document.getNodeRef(), ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT,
                    true);
            writerDoc.putContent(file/inputStream);
            ```
   2. In your context file, declare you action :

      ```
      <bean id="my-action" class="x.y.z.MyAction" parent="action-executer">
          <property name="searchService">
              <ref bean="searchService" />
          </property>
          <property name="nodeService">
              <ref bean="nodeService" />
          </property>
          <property name="contentService">
              <ref bean="contentService" />
          </property>
          <property name="fileFolderService">
              <ref bean="FileFolderService" />
          </property>
          ....
      </bean>
      ```
2. In Share, assign to a folder a rule with the action you have created.

Comment: Hi Akah, Your guess is correct. i wanted to update those values in word document only. but i didn't found any proper code on the links you provided. can you please suggest some other proper way. means not able to do anything with the solution you provided. i need some more explanation and help. please reply.

Comment: Hi all, Actually my requirement is changed a bit. now i want to extract metadata from excel sheet and i want to inject in to word document. Please suggest the way.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, how do you want it to work ? When you drop/update an excel in the same folder as on or multiple documents, it is updated with the values ?

Comment: Hi Akah, actually your question is correct. actually now my requirement is, i have suppose 10 employee information in excel sheet. i already read this information using poi api. Now my requirement is  i have one appraisal letter template, and based on excel sheet data i want to create 10 appraisal letters. means appraisal letter template is fixed for every employee. so i just want to replace some values like Employee id,  Employee name, Employee Grade etc.  Now i have two challenges. 1st is to replace info in doc template. and 2nd is where to keep excel in alfresco & where to keep doc template

Comment: If you understood my exact requirement, please suggest the possibilities to do this.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: OK, so if I resume well : 1-You have somewhere a template Word you want to use as a base to create letters. 2-If you drop an excel in a specific folder, you want ten word letters automatically created (one for each excel row) and filled with the excel columns

Comment: Perfect, That is only my requirement. I will upload one excel, and i am planning to keep word template in document library folder of alfresco.

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what i was looking for. Tomorrow I will try the way you provided.

Comment: Hi Akah, I have ContentWriterobject. and now my requirment is ti convert it in to file/inputStream.   Because As per you told in step 3 i used writerDoc.putContent() method but i dont have inputstream object to pass for this method.    i used like this writerDoc.putContent(doc.getDocumentText()); But it replacing in only first line of document.   Can you help me with this.

Comment: Maybe something like this ? writerDoc.putContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.getDataStream())). But be careful about the memory this kind of operation can take.

Comment: I tried this, But now it's deleting all contents of document. And target Document size became zero bytes. Can you provide any other way or sample code to replace text. Before this i created custom action to call java code,  i also successfully read  excel data, also i found node reference of target document. but now i am not able to replace data. Thank you so much as you already helped me a lot. but still i Stuck for replacing it. Please help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never done exactly this kind of thing. Maybe pass by a tempfile (with the TempFileProvider.createTempFile() method). You'll be able to copy the template in it, make your modifications, save and then copy the temp file in your target node.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try it. :)

Comment: Hi Akah, Finally i have done with bulk upload task in alfresco. its very big achievement for me. Thanks a lot for your help. It become possible because of you only.  Thanks again :)